# Matching an unknown number of multi-lines an unknown number of lines with Select-String in Powershell?

Tags: regex, powershell, select-string

I've been able to match multiple lines; but only if I know how many lines are coming, and what the content of those lines are...

```
Select-String -Pattern "^Timestamp: 3/27/2021.*`n`n|^Message:.*errorText:" -Context 2 -LiteralPath .\SomeLog.log
```

Is there a way to match multiple lines without knowing what is in between?

for instance to match

```
[START]
...
...
[END]
```

I read something about changing the [settings to the regex with (?sme)](https://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html) but it doesn't seem to work.

I was trying something like the following:

`Select-String -Pattern '(sme?)\[START\].*\n(.*\n)\+\[END\]'`

Comment: There is no `e` flag in .NET regex flavor, and `?` is  placed right after `(`. Just use `Get-Content $fpath -Raw | Select-String -Pattern '(?s)\[START].*?\[END]' -AllMatches | % { $_.matches.value }`

Comment: See (prototype in) propose: [`#15136` Add `-From` and `-To` parameters to `Select-String`](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/15136)

Comment: The file could have Windows format newlines (CRLF). You're now assuming it has *nix style (LF only)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) match *multiline* substrings:

- You must provide the input as a *single, multiline* string, which is what [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content)'s `-Raw` switch provides.
- As needed, in the regex passed to `Select-String`'s `-Pattern` parameter, use inline [regex option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-options) `m` (multi-line) to make `^` and `$` match the beginning and end of *each line* (`(?m)`) and/or option `s` (single-line) to make `.` match newline characters (`` "`n" ``) too (`(?s)`); you can activate *both* with `(?sm)`.

Here's an example with a multiline [here-string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#here-strings) serving as input, instead of, say,
`Get-Content -Raw file.txt`:

```sh
(@'
before
[START]
...1
...2
[END]
after
[START]
...3
...4
[END]
done
'@ | 
  Select-String  -AllMatches -Pattern '(?sm)^\[START\]$.+?^\[END\]$'
).Matches.Value -join "`n------------------------`n"
```

<sup>Note: Strictly speaking, only `[`, not also `]`, requires escaping with `\`.</sup>

If you only want to find the *first* block of matching lines, omit `-AllMatches`.<sup>Thanks, [Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%c5%bcew).</sup>
`-AllMatches` requests returning all matches *per input string*, and is normally - with *line-by-line* input - used to find multiple matches *per line*. Here, with a *multiline* input string, all (potentially multiline) matches inside *it* are returned.

Output:

```
[START]
...1
...2
[END]
------------------------
[START]
...3
...4
[END]
```

---

If you want to **return only what is *between* the delimiter lines**:

```sh
(@'
before
[START]
...1
...2
[END]
after
[START]
...3
...4
[END]
done
'@ | 
  Select-String  -AllMatches -Pattern '(?sm)^\[START\]\r?\n(.*?)\r?\n\[END\]$'
).Matches.ForEach({ $_.Groups[1].Value }) -join "`n------------------------`n"
```

<sup>Note: `\r?\n` matches both Windows-format CRLF and Unix-format LF-only newlines. Use `\r\n` / `\n` to match only the former / latter.</sup>

Output:

```
...1
...2
------------------------
...3
...4
```